# C# Linq questions on select parameters

Tags: c#, linq

I have the basic understanding of select method in linq.

```
var arrayIndex = Enumerable.Range(10, 10).ToArray();
```

This one will create an array with integers 10 to 19.

For some real life problems, I need to use the index of the original data.

After some research, I found that I can do something like this

```
var multipliedArray = arrayIndex.Select((i, Index) => i * Index).ToArray();
```

I know that i is the item itself, in this case i will be integer.

So, just two questions

1. How do I know the full list of parameters that can put within the bracket (like the Index).
2. What's the other use case for having different parameter in the bracket.

Comment: You type in `arrayIndex.Select(` and observe the popup with the overloads? Or you press F1 on `Select` and read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) directly?

Comment: There are only two overloads of `Select`, one with and without the index. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select)

Answer (score 0):

For a better understanding, you can refer to the [relevant document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) Or using Code Completion in development environments.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The part within the `Select`...

```
(i, Index) => i * Index
```

...is lambda expression, which is equivalent to an anonymous method. If you would write the method non-anonymously, it would look like this:

```
int Calculate(int i, int Index) {
    return i * Index;
}
```

When you want to pass a method as an argument, the respective parameter needs to be a delegate that matches the method's signature. The given `Calculate` nethod and, since they are sharing the same signature, your lambda expression match the signaturee of the [`Func<int, int, int>` delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-3?view=netframework-4.8). As it turns out, `Enumerable.Select<int, int>`offers you [an overload with exactly this delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Select__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32___1__), so you can use your lambda expression. The other (more widely used) overload accepts a `Func<int, int>`, which is the version without the index. There are no other overloads, so you can not have other arguments in your lambda expression.